# How to reserve ram for ramdisk (tmpfs) but also prevent it from swaping

Tags: tmpfs, ramdisk

## My scenario:

I have a server with 256GB of ram and I want to create a ram disk, with let's say a 224GB size. Now, I know that there are two main types for ramdisk - ramfs & tmpfs (taken from [here](https://www.jamescoyle.net/knowledge/951-the-difference-between-a-tmpfs-and-ramfs-ram-disk)):

1. ramfs file systems cannot be limited in size like a disk base file system which is limited by it’s capacity. ramfs will continue using memory storage until the system runs out of RAM .
2. tmpfs is a more recent RAM file system - You can specify a size limit in tmpfs which will give a ‘disk full’ error when the limit is reached.

As it seems, tmpfs is the way to go. But after creating the ramdisk using:

```
>  mount -t tmpfs -o size=512m tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk
```

I noticed that 224GB ram is not actually guaranteed for the ramdisk (free -g gives 256GB free memory without cache)

So, from what I understand tmpfs gives a "barrier" for maximum ram to be used (224GB in my case), but it doesn't guarantee that memory for the ramdisk.

## My Question:

How do I prevent other applications from accessing my ram (the 224GB portion). I don't want a get to a scenario where instead of saving to my ramdisk, I am saving to swap.

=========== Update =============

I found [this](http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/Ramdisk/ramdisk.html) .
It looks a bit "old school", but it could be a solution to my problem.

Comment: A tmpfs filesystem only uses as much memory as required (currently in use)...Those you could create a loopback file with the needed size inside the tmpfs!